# How can I disable the network status notification bubbles?

Tags: wireless, networking, notification

I'm using the latest version of Ubuntu, with a Wi-Fi adaptor that Ubuntu detected flawlessly.

When the internet drops out, Ubuntu gives me a notification bubble in the top right of the screen, e.g. "Wireless network, Disconnected".  There is no clickable "x" on these notifications and I can't seem to stop them from returning over and over and over, about once every 5 seconds.  To make matters worse, I can't access the network settings menu in the top right of the screen, because every time I open the network settings meny, a notification bubble pops up and cancels the menu.  This means I can't configure my network, which is what Ubuntu is complaining about.

So, the short question: how can I disable those notification bubbles?  Or, what must I do to acknowledge a bubble so that it doesn't pop up again and again and again unless there has been a significant other event?

Comment: Use patched version of notify-osd from Leolik's PPA: https://launchpad.net/~leolik/+archive/leolik. Then you can able to close the bubble with left click.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
[Ubuntu disable popup notifications](http://viewsby.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/ubuntu-disable-popup-notifications/)

Then do the opposite to reenable them.  I'd post this as a comment, but I'm 4 rep short.

Answer (score 0):

Works beautifully @eyoung100.    I put it into a script in case anybody else is interested.

```
#!/bin/bash
enabled=/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service
disabled=/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service.disabled
if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "To turn off notifications, type toggleNotify off"
    echo "To turn on  notifications, type toggleNotify on"
    echo "-h print help"
    echo "-t report whether notifications are on or off"
    exit
elif [ $1 = "-h" ] ; then
    toggleNotify
elif [ $1 = "-t" ] ; then
    if test -f $enabled ; then
        echo "notifications are on" 
    else
        echo "notifications are off"    
    fi
    exit
elif [ $1 = "on" ] ; then
    if test -f $disabled ; then
        echo "Turning on notifications"
        sudo mv $disabled $enabled
    fi
elif [ $1 = "off" ] ; then
    if test -f $enabled ; then
        echo "Turning off notifications"
        sudo mv $enabled $disabled
        killall notify-osd
    fi
else
    #to get the help message
    toggleNotify
fi
```